# I have a string and want to replace all the values in a string in one go

Tags: python

```
str1 = "series of sentences that are organized and coherent, and are all related to a single topic. Almost every piece of writing you do that is longer than a few **sentences** should be organized into paragraphs."

REPLACE_STRING = {"series":"web" , "sentence":"long paragraph"}
```

Output:

```
web of long paragraph that are organized and coherent, and are all related to a single topic. Almost every piece of writing you do that is longer than a few **long paragraph** should be organized into paragraphs.
```

Basically need to replace all values in a str with the key present in the dictionary in one go.

Comment: Sounds like something you could use `re.sub` for.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: If you change the `**...**` to `{...}` you can use `res = str1.format(**REPLACE_STRING)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for key, value in REPLACE_STRING.items():
    str1 = str1.replace(key, value)

print(str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one go:

```py
str1 = str1.replace('series', 'web').replace('sentence', 'long paragraph')
```

Using a loop:

```py
for to_replace, replace_with in REPLACE_STRING.items():
    str1 = str1.replace(to_replace, replace_with)
```